# Explanation of the Angular Momentum of the Electromagnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, noethers-theorem, poynting-vector

The fact that the EM field carries angular momentum is a well-accepted fact, and I've been trying to look into ways of showing it. I have two: One using Noether's Theorem, other using the Poynting Vector. But, in both of them, there are parts that I've been not able to properly show.

Starting with the first one, we do have a nice simple result for the Lagrangian Density of the EM field:

\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{L}=\frac{1}{8\pi}(E^2-B^2)
\end{equation}
Where the Lagrangian Density is defined in terms of the spatial integral which defines the Lagrangian itself:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\int d^dr\ \mathfrak{L}
\end{equation}
Well, understanding the action of the system as the integral of the Lagrangian over time, we can define the action for the EM field:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}=\int d^drdt\ \mathfrak{L}\ \Longrightarrow\ \mathcal{S}=\frac{1}{8\pi}\int d^3rdt(E^2-B^2)
\end{equation}
Interpretating a rotation as an absolute change of direction, wields that the following transformation represents a rotation:
\begin{equation}
r\longmapsto r'
\end{equation}
If we can show that $S$ is invariant under this transformation, that is, it has rotational symmetry, we can then conclude that that is a Angular Momentum associated with the field, using Noether's Theorem, since angular momentum is the conserved quantity associated with rotational symmetries.

Well, obviously, I skipped some parts: I didn't show where the equation for the Lagrangian Density came from, and I also did not show that the action has rotational invariance, which comes from developing the equations for time-varying electric and magnetic fields, which I do not know how to properly do.

The second approach gives an explicit form for the Angular Momentum. The Poynting Vector is defined as it follows:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{S}=\epsilon_0 c^2\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}
\end{equation}
A vector that gives the direction of propagation of the electromagnetic energy in the field. We can recall that the energy–momentum tensor describes both density and flux of energy and momentum in the space-time, and it's components are given by the matrix:
\begin{equation}
T^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
      T^{00} & T^{01} & T^{02} & T^{03} \\ T^{10} & T^{11} & T^{12} & T^{13} \\ T^{20} & T^{21} & T^{22} & T^{23} \\ T^{30} & T^{31} & T^{32} & T^{33}\end{pmatrix}, \ \mu,\nu=1,2,3
\end{equation}

It can be shown that it's symmetric:
\begin{equation}
    T^{\mu\nu}=T^{\nu\mu}
\end{equation}
Which I took to interprete that density (or flux) of energy and momentum mean the same thing. Going further, if we look at the mass–energy equivalence:
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
We can associate a momentum density $\mathfrak{g}$ with the Ponyting Vector:
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{g}=\frac{1}{c^2}\mathbf{S}=\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}
\end{equation}
But we define the angular momentum as $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$. Then we can obtain a form for the angular momentum of the EM field by integrating the momentum density in 3d-space:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{L}=\epsilon_0\int\mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B)}\ d^3r
\end{equation}
Which concludes the second approach. In this one, I did not prove how is the energy-momentum tensor symmetric, nor did I show under what conditions it holds.

So, summarizing, I want to know how to do those things I didn't, and if those developments are reasonable. If anyone can help, I'll be grateful.